# I am getting an infinite loop

Tags: python, infinite-loop

Whenever i run this I am getting an infinite loop printing out "Higher"
I have tried moving things around and playing with the indentation to no avail

```
# Guess My Number
#
# The computer picks a random number between 1 and 100
# The player tries to guess it and the computer lets
# the player know if the guess is too high, too low # or right on the money

import random

#set initial values

print("This is guess my number\nI'm thinking of a number between 0-100")

#generate number
def ask_number():
    """Ask for a number within a range."""
    the_number = random.randint(1,100)
    guess = int(float())
    tries = 1
    question = (input("Take a guess: "))
    print(question)
    
    while guess != the_number:
        if guess < the_number:
            print("Higher...")
        else:
            print("Lower...")      
    guess = int(input("try again: "))
    tries += 1 
           
    if guess == the_number:
        
        print("Well done, the number was", the_number)
        print("It took you", tries, "attempt/s")

ask_number()

input("\n\nPress enter key to exit")
```

Comment: Neither `guess` nor `the_number` change inside the loop body. Why then would the loop condition change?

Answer (score 5):

```
while guess != the_number:
    if guess < the_number:
        print("Higher...")
    else:
        print("Lower...")
```

There is no `input()` statement in this loop, so `guess` remains unchanged, and therefore the loop runs forever.